# install brother mfc7360n scanner

Tags: scanner, brother

I am looking to install brother MFC 7360. I have installed printer but as scanner concerned it is not working every time when I try to run `xsane` it says device not connected,

When I try to add `brscan-skey` to startup program it asks for command line.
I am not sure what shall I write in command line.

Comment: "For Brother USB scanners"
"look at lsusb for the id like 04f9 is and save the file Restart udev sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart or sudo service udev restart" could you explain how to save the file for the info I see when typing lsusb?

Answer (score 4):

For USB you have to edit the `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` with root-rights and insert

```
# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

in top of

```
# The following rule will disable ...
```

look at `lsusb` for the id like 04f9 is and save the file
Restart udev
`sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart` or `sudo service udev restart`

good luck
mick

Answer (score 2):

I got the scanner to work (internet connected) by entering this command from: [MaXSoftProjects: How to install MFC-7360N Brother on Ubuntu 12.04 for Ethernet (Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605212515/http://www.maxsoftprojects.com/2012/05/how-to-installa-mfc-7360n-on-ubuntu.html)

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=SCANNER model=MFC7360N ip=192.168.1.53
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download driver to this [link](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan-0.2.4-0.i386.deb&lang=English_sane).
2. Open terminal.
3. Go to folder with driver downloaded.
4. `sudo dpkg  -i  --force-all**  (scanner-drivername)`
5. Now you can use your scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605212515/http://www.maxsoftprojects.com/2012/05/how-to-installa-mfc-7360n-on-ubuntu.html).

In the Brother website download page, you should check for matching version (MFC-7360n), I think brscan4 should work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
wget http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006646/brscan4-0.4.1-5.i386.deb
wget http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006654/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
dpkg -i brscan4*.deb
dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1*.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this printer and had the same problem.

I enabled printing, but scanning was not forthcoming.

I installed the drivers provided by [this list of Brother scanner drivers](https://web.archive.org/web/20120914014458/http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html), but was still unsuccessful.

After some work and research, I found that SANE (Scanner Access Now Easy) -- the API that provides access to the scanner in GNU/Linux -- does not currently support scanner connectivity over the network, so I hooked up my printer/scanner via USB and was able to connect... sort of. I also had to change the permissions of the device.

To find out where the printer was mounted:

```
lsusb
```

Output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b175 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 4-Port Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04f9:0270 Brother Industries, Ltd
```

Then changed the device permissions (full access for everyone):

```
chmod 777 /dev/bus/usb/002/007
```

Now I'm able to use the Ubuntu simple scan utility to do scanning as long as I'm connected via USB.

Does anyone have any solutions for Network scanning on this model?

Comment: Giving world access to your usb port is BAD.  The correct way to fix the permissions issue is described Michael Lang's answer above.  I highly recommend deleting this answer before someone more strict down votes it.