# Install drivers for Brother MFC 7360N printer/scanner/fax

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, brother

I'm running Ubuntu and want to install my Brother MFC 7360N printer scanner fax. I've tried to just plug in the USB cable, but the only two drivers Ubuntu shows don't work. One of them doesn't react at all and the other prints only blank pages.

I've found the [MaXSoftProjects tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605212515/http://www.maxsoftprojects.com/2012/05/how-to-installa-mfc-7360n-on-ubuntu.html) referenced by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/341985/955434), but I have no idea what "CUPS" are or any of that other stuff.

Comment: Have a look at [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1784369)

Answer (score 3):

Translated with Google Translate:

BROTHER MFC- 7360N to connected USB port for printer configuration Ubuntu 10.04 and following ( localhost ) :

```
Download drivers at the following addresses ( deb recommended.) : MFC- 7360N # http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html
```

Install drivers through the Ubuntu repository.

```
Go to System Settings > Printing .
Click Add, and then specify as device URI : usb :/ / Brother/MFC-7360N serial = EXXXXXXXXXXXXX (with sérial machine located by the screen of the printer in Menu Button > 6 Device Info ? . > 1.No series ( Warning: eg if No. E69719 - series = F2N979180 then serial = E69719F2N979180 think about removing the dash) .
In choosing a driver > Provide PPD file > Select File > File System > usr > share> ppd (you should see a file ppd MFC7360N.ppd ) Select .
Define names for the final configuration and then click apply and print the test page .
Optional: you can specify / dev/usb/lp0 in the location section by double-clicking the printer.
```

BROTHER MFC- 7360N to connected USB port for printer configuration Ubuntu 10.04 and following ( localhost ) :

```
Download drivers at the following addresses ( deb recommended.) : MFC- 7360N # http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html
```

Install drivers through the Ubuntu repository.

```
Go to System Settings > Printing .
Click Add, and then specify as device URI : usb :/ / Brother/MFC-7360N serial = EXXXXXXXXXXXXX (with sérial machine located by the screen of the printer in Menu Button > 6 Device Info ? . > 1.No series ( Warning: eg if No. E69719 - series = F2N979180 then serial = E69719F2N979180 think about removing the dash) .
In choosing a driver > Provide PPD file > Select File > File System > usr > share> ppd (you should see a file ppd MFC7360N.ppd ) Select .
Define names for the final configuration and then click apply and print the test page .
Optional: you can specify / dev/usb/lp0 in the location section by double-clicking the printer.
```

Answer (score 2):

CUPS is the print server on most Linux and Mac machines. It was a project started by Apple many many years ago and it's a fairly robust system for handling printers.

Brother's Linux support for this printer is a little sketchy. They have a "cupswrapper" driver for it which is sort of a compatibility layer around an ancient LPR driver. I honestly can't say how effective it will be.

Anyway download the deb drivers from here (you need both cupswrapper and LPR files):

- http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-7360

Save those somewhere, then in a terminal, `cd` into that directory and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all mfc*.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all cupswrapper*.deb
```

And then load the CUPS printer configuration page (`http://localhost:631/printers`) and edit the printer you've already set up with the following information:

- "LPD/LPR Host or Printer" or "AppSocket/HP JetDirect"             for Device
- lpd://(Your printer's IP address)/binary_p1           for Device URI
- Brother           for Make/Manufacturer Selection
- Your printer's name           for Model/Driver Selection

The above is a paraphrasing and slimming of [the instructions from Brother](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html). I've no idea if they actually work!

Comment: Worked! But I didnt need to do anything past running the 2 sudo commands you gave me. I think that is because it is just a local printer. Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Drivers have moved to: http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html
Also check Brothers:
http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc7360n_all&redirect=on
Thanks for this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The much superior, actively(?)* maintained [**brlaser**](https://github.com/pdewacht/brlaser) supports this and many other printers:
<sup>*last commit: Feb 20, 2023</sup>

> This driver has been reported to work with these printers:
>
> - Brother DCP-1510 series
> - Brother DCP-1600 series
> - Brother DCP-7030
> - Brother DCP-7040
> - Brother DCP-7055
> - Brother DCP-7055W
> - Brother DCP-7060D
> - Brother DCP-7065DN
> - Brother DCP-7080
> - Brother DCP-L2500D series
> - Brother DCP-L2520D series
> - Brother DCP-L2520DW series
> - Brother DCP-L2540DW series
> - Brother HL-1110 series
> - Brother HL-1200 series
> - Brother HL-2030 series
> - Brother HL-2140 series
> - Brother HL-2220 series
> - Brother HL-2270DW series
> - Brother HL-5030 series
> - Brother HL-L2300D series
> - Brother HL-L2320D series
> - Brother HL-L2340D series
> - Brother HL-L2360D series
> - Brother HL-L2375DW series
> - Brother HL-L2390DW
> - Brother MFC-1910W
> - Brother MFC-7240
> - **Brother MFC-7360N**
> - Brother MFC-7365DN
> - Brother MFC-7420
> - Brother MFC-7460DN
> - Brother MFC-7840W
> - Brother MFC-L2710DW series
> - Lenovo M7605D