# Printer Brother MFC-7360N can't print on LAN

Tags: networking, printing

I'm trying to set my network printer 'Brother MFC-7360N' on my LAN. All laptops are using Ubuntu 14.04, and I've installed the cups and lpd drivers from Brother, but I can't print on LAN. The printer shows that I can add the printer, see the cartridge status, but when I send something to print nothing happens, and I get no warnings or errors. I've followed a lot of forums and posts but it's no good.

Answer (score 3):

I have a Brother MFC-7840W printer connected over LAN. I had a similar issue where if I installed a printer using the **Settings > Printer install wizard**, it would detect the network printer and install it, *but no print jobs* would go through when the printer went to *sleep*.

I have got it working finally, after manually trying many combinations.  This is how I got it to work, waking up the printer and finally print my jobs:

1. Set up the printer to use a **static ip address**. Mine is at 192.168.1.10
2. Use **Settings > Printers > Add printer** to auto detect the printer on the network
3. Determine its **print queue name**, mine was called 'mfc7840w'.
4. Remove the auto installed printer, we only installed it to get its print queue name.
5. Open you web browser to this URL `http://localhost:631` to access the CUPS admin pages
6. Click on the **Administration** tab
7. Click on **Add Printer**
8. Select **LPD/LPR**:
9. Enter this URL: `lpd://192.168.1.10/mfc7840w` where `mfc7840w` is your printer's print queue name:
10. Browse for your Printer's **Make/Model** and then click on the **Add Printer** button
11. Make any changes to the default settings and click on **Set Defaults**
12. Try printing a test page, and hopefully it will work for you.

These instructions worked on my two Ubuntu 14.04 computers (same OS but different hardware), and my OSX 10.7.5 computer!  So it has worked 3 times for me.

Comment: BTW it is a MFC 7360N.

Answer (score 0):

The following is worth trying even if it's in reference to Ubuntu 13.

> "I have been banging my head against the wall in trying to get my Brother MFC-7360N printer scanner copier fax machine to work with Ubuntu 12 and Ubuntu 13.
>
> Nothing would work. Researched lots... still couldn't get it to work. Finally got it to print from Ubuntu 13 just fine due to a stupidly obvious (maybe) fix. So thought I would share how I fixed mine.
>
> This is for a device connected directly to PC via USB.
>
> As per: [Install Brother MFC 7360N for beginners](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280644/install-brother-mfc-7360n-for-beginners)
>
> Brother's Linux support for this printer is a little sketchy. They have a "cupswrapper" driver for it which is sort of a compatibility layer around an ancient LPR driver. I honestly can't say how effective it will be.
>
> Anyway download the deb drivers from here (you need both cupswrapper and LPR files):
>
> http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-7360
>   Save those somewhere, then in a terminal, cd into that directory and run:
>
> `sudo dpkg -i --force-all mfc*.deb`
>   `sudo dpkg -i --force-all cupswrapper*.deb`
>
> Following that, no matter what, still couldnt get it to run.
>   So referring to: http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html
>   I noted that it specified you needed to check that Ubuntu's printer settings had the right USB address.
>
> And mine wasn't.
>
> Printers > (MFC-7360N) > Properties > Device URI:
>
> I noted that mine was different... so connected printer via USB, hit change in Device URI, selected the printer line there (being usb://Brother/MFC-7360N wotever).
>
> Apply
>
> And tadahh... all my queued up "Printer is not available' printjobs came spewing out.
>
> Works.
>
> So in the end it was all down to the Ubuntu Printer settings, not a base level Brother driver issue after all.
>
> Hope this can help any other frustrated Brother owners."

[source](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2128069)

Comment: thanks for the help but what I realy need is to get the printer connected from my network, not from usb